# How to store uploaded images into an array | Rails && Angular && JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, azure

I am using Rails and Javascript, and I have an Angular Front-end. I still relatively new to development; starting to get the hang of it, but I don't know how to target images in my (PGsql)server. Would it make it easier for me to target images, if I push all submitted photos into an array?

I am testing vision APIs; I would like to find a way to upload an image and store them in an array, so that I can send a POST request to an external API(Azure/AWS Vision APIs etc.)--using the photo that was submitted.

I hope, this would make it easier to dynamically send requests on submit; in addition to rendering the JSON response in a view.

**Form partial**

```
<%= simple_form_for @image, :class => "form_id", :html => {:multipart
=> true} do |f| %>  <%= f.input :title, label: "Name of Photo" %>   <%= f.input :image, as: :file, :onChange => "alertMe(this.files[0])",
label: "Submit Image to Render Tags!" %>    <%= f.button :submit,
:onsubmit => "imgPush();", :onclick => "return sendFileRequest();",
:class => "form_id" %>   <% end %>
```

**App.js**

```
$scope.alertMe = function () {

var params = {
    // Request parameters
    "visualFeatures": "Categories,Tags",
    "details": "Celebrities",
};



$.ajax({
         url: "https://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1.0/analyze?" + $.param(params),
         beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
             // Request headers
             xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
             xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","this is my key");
         },
         type: "POST",
         // Request body
         data: "{\"url\":\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/17/Batman-BenAffleck.jpg\"}"

     })
     .done(function(data) {
         alert("success");

     })
     .fail(function(jqHQR, status) {
         alert("error : " + jqHQR + " status " + status);
     });

 }
```

Comment: What does your code look like? Have you tried converting the images to base64 or a bit string?

Comment: @Fernando, I've updated.

Comment: According the description at https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa, the API dose not support such image urls or raw data in array.

Answer (score 0):

According the description at https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa, the API dose not support such image urls or raw data in array.

If you want to analyze a list of images, you can try to upload your images to your backend server, then generate a list of rest calls with the content of images against to the API.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Liu, Below, you will find an example of JS code; they are using "{body}", I assume, this is a way to iterate through their images that they are sending to Azure.

Comment: Liu, Below, you will find a link to an example of JS code; they are using "{body}", I assume, this is a way to iterate through their images that they are sending to Azure.   https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa

Comment: How are you able to use this body object, "{body}"? I get an [Object object] error, if I use body, but it works with a URL. I would like to use the images that I've upload from the form and send my POST request--onSubmit. How can I dynamically render the JSON response in the view? I'm quite blocked. @Gary Liu - MSFT

Comment: Please try in JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/maqbzv15/2492/, change the **Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key** to your own at first.